# Finding probability... Two numbers selected from a set of natural numbers

Tags: probability

Two numbers $r$ and $s$ are drawn one at a time, without replacement from the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ 
Find $P(r\leq p/s\leq p)$ where $p$ belongs to the set

Comment: $p/s \le p$ seems unnecessary. Check the source to make sure you stated the problem correctly.

Comment: I agree it seems unnecessary but that's how the question is. The question can still be solved

Comment: Is the answer supposed to be expressed in terms of the unknown $p$?

Comment: I don't have the answer sorry.

Comment: But I think that since p can be anything it should in terms of that

Answer (score 0):

Fix an integer $n>1$.

If $r,s$ are drawn randomly, one at a time, without replacement, from $\{1,...,n\}$, then for fixed $p \in \{1,...,n\}$, the probability that $r \le {\large{\frac{p}{s}}} \le p\;$can be expressed as
$$
\frac
{
{\displaystyle{
\left(
\sum_{r=1}^p \left\lfloor{\frac{p}{r}}\right\rfloor
\right)
-\lfloor{\sqrt{p}}\rfloor
}}
}
{
\phantom{\large{X^X}}{n(n-1)}\phantom{\large{X^X}}
}
$$

Comment: How!I don't understand how you got P^1/2

Comment: You need to subtract off the counts for the pairs $(r,r)$ where $r^2 \le p$.

Comment: Test the formula for small values of $n$ and $p$.